# Django admin/ return 404

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls, django-settings

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Not Found: /admin/
[30/May/2021 20:33:56] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2097

project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
        path('', include('marketability.mkbl_urls')),
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    ]
```

variants `path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),` and `path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),` don't works too.

project/marketability/mkbl_urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView, TemplateView
from . import views

app_name = 'marketability'

handler404 = 'marketability.views.handler404'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('<slug:cat_>/', views.page_Category_Main, name='cat'),
    path('<slug:cat_>/<slug:product_>', views.page_Product, name='product'),
    path('al_about.html', views.about, name="about"),
    path('al_home.html', views.home, name="home"),
    path('search_all.html', views.search_all, name="doorway"),
    path('robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="robots.txt", content_type="text/plain")),
    path('sitemap.xml', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="sitemap.xml", content_type="text/xml")),
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/marketability/favicon.ico', permanent=True)),
]
```

project/marketability/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import TxtHow, TxtRatings

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(TxtHow)
admin.site.register(TxtRatings)
```

project/settings.py

```
....
NSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'marketability',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/marketability/patterns'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
....
```

`superuser` has created

So, i don't see any deviations from Django Documentation.
How to solve it?
thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path:

```
path('<slug:cat_>/', views.page_Category_Main, name='cat'),
```

will match with `admin/` and thus see `admin` as the value for the `cat_` slug, and thus trigger that view. Likely the view for that path will try to fetch an element with `admin` as slug, and fail to do this, and thus raise a HTTP 404 response.

You can put the urls for the `admin/` and `ckeditor/` before the one with your categories:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('', include('marketability.mkbl_urls')),
]
```

Django will visit the url patterns top to bottom, and thus trigger the first path pattern that matches, in that case the one with the admin.

It might however be better to prefix your `marketability` urls as well, for example with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('market/', include('marketability.mkbl_urls')),
]
```

otherwise it is thus impossible to have a category named `admin`.